# Building database schema Laravel4 vs Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

To make it clear let's make classic example - User and Post.

Creating db schema in Symfony2 is clean and simple:

- we create entities Post and User
- additionaly we can simply add columns/indexes to each.
- then just add value with `OneToMany` annotation in User and `ManyToOne` in Post
- ..well, that's it. Now if we run `db:schema:update --force` and we can get what we want - database schema and simple adding another rows in database.

What about Laravel4? So far only solution I found:

- create/generate Post and User models
- declare in each model which table it refers to
- create migrations and in Post migration add foregin key to user_id column
- run migration
- add in each model methods in which we refer to the other model (hasMany, belongsTo .. )

As I wrote it, it doesn't seem so complicated, but it's not so concentrated in Laravel as it is in Symfony. I'm kinda lazy person and I really enjoy the process in Symfony, while in Laravel it is a little bit too diffuse. Is there any simpler ( lazier :P ) way to do this in Laravel? Something like creating schema based on Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question makes sense but unfortunately there isn't such functionality on Laravel at the moment.

As opposed to running migrations from your models (symfony) you must create the migrations first, the you can use the models to seed database tables if they have foreign keys.

I use the Jeffrey Way Generators https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

to speed up the process so for example if I have a users table and a profile table (many to many) then I would perform these tasks on command line:

```
php artisan generate:migration create_users_table --fields="username:string, password:string, email:string"
php artisan generate:migration create_profiles_table --fields="name:string, lastname:string, phone:string"

php artisan migrate

php artisan generate:pivot users profiles

php artisan migrate
```

Then you can create your models (you can also generate an entire CRUD resource or Scaffold)

```
php artisan generate:model user
php artisan generate:model profile
```

Then in your User Model

```
public function profile()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Profile');
}
```

In your Profile Model

```
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

Comment: well, that's a pitty. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @mmmm is there any tool to do the syncing 3 years and 4 months after the question was asked?

Comment: I haven't touched Laravel since 3 years and and 1 month, so I don't really know :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some plugins / commands that speed up the development.

For example [Jeffrey Way's Laravel-4-Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators)

Comment: "create/generate Post and User models" - I'm aware of generators. What I'm looking for is to not detach models from migrations, generally speaking.